# Monitor traffic in a java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, web, monitoring

I'm looking for something that can monitor the traffic of a java web application in order to estimate cloud computing prices.

It would be great if it can categorize the traffic in different categories, e.g. database, static resources, pages, etc.

Ideally, it should be something working in the same way New Relic does. Unfortunately, New Relic only monitors times and not traffic...

Does something like this exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any java-specific software for doing that. You can use any network monitor tool and just run your application locally! For monitoring different kind of traffic, I would use different tools too. There are a lot of DB-monitor tools out there... Sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot solutions for monitoring Java web applications. I have tried a few of them but finally stopped at two: Zabbix and JavaMelody. Both are appropriate to monitor and categorize a traffic of apps, although they are completely different in how they work. Zabbix allows watching an app over the long term via JMX. JavaMelody can be built into an app and provides complete insight into business app processes.

Your final decision about Java app monitoring platform depends on the prioritized app features that you’d like to monitor. I recommend you to read the review that helps you look at both solutions in details:  http://cases.azoft.com/enterprise-system-monitoring-solutions-business-apps/